# UICollectionViewCell with a dynamic image dimensions - As u scroll, the image loses its initial constraints when the cell is re-used TestApp attached

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, constraints, uicollectionviewcell

I would like some assistance please.

I have a UICollectionViewCell for an onBoarding scenario each cell contains one image with different dimensions that are set dynamically.

I am using WWLayout similar to SnapKit to handle the constrains.

The issue is when I swipe thru and the cell is re-used the constraints break and the image loses its initial dimensions.

I have attached a TestApp.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tx141lpr0uzlhbx/Test%20App.Image.Resize.zip?dl=0

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `OnBoardingItemView.swift`, function `layoutUI()`, just before you layout `imageView`, try adding this line:

```
imageView.removeConstraints(imageView.constraints)
```

Comment: Ofcourse I completely forgot to remove the constraints as well. I ended up adding imageView.removeConstraints() inside prepareForReuse(), Thank you so much 

Answer (score 0):

The image was not being scaled properly. Update your code with this one to prevent the image from stretching.

```
private lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return imageView
}()
```

This variable is in OnBoardingItemView.swift, line 35